# Need to form tree json from json record set

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Am using angularjs as front-end and nodejs as service provider. NodeJS send data to angularjs in JSON object.

```
 $scope.data =  
        [
            {"id": 53,"title": "Scene 1","sc_parentnodes": 0},
            {"id": 54,"title": "Scene 1.1","sc_parentnodes": 53},
            {"id": 55,"title": "Scene 1.2","sc_parentnodes": 53},
            {"id": 56,"title": "Scene 2","sc_parentnodes": 0},
            {"id": 57,"title": "Scene 2.1","sc_parentnodes": 56},
            {"id": 58,"title": "Scene 2.2","sc_parentnodes": 56}
        ]
```

But i need to bind data on angular-ui-treetable in the below format,

```
    $scope.data =    [
           {   "id": 53,
                "title": "Scene 1",
                "sc_parentnodes":
                                 [
                                    {"id": 54,"title": "Scene 1.1","sc_parentnodes": []},
                                    {"id": 55,"title": "Scene 1.2","sc_parentnodes": []}
                                ]
            },
            {   "id": 56,
                "title": "Scene 2",
                "sc_parentnodes": [
                                    {"id": 57,"title": "Scene 2.1","sc_parentnodes": []},
                                    {"id": 58,"title": "Scene 2.2","sc_parentnodes": 56}
                                  ]
            }
        ]
```

Is there any predefined library/function to frame tree structure in jquery or angularjs.

Comment: No, you have to construct your data in the format you want. What are the `**` for? They ruin your json and are syntax errors.

Comment: I just want to highlight(bold) element.

Comment: Oh, got it. You can't in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.each($scope.data,function(index1,val1) {
    $.each($scope.data,function(index,val) {
       if(val.id == val1.sc_parentnodes && val1.sc_parentnodes!=0 ) {
          array.push($scope.data[index]);
       }
    }
   val1.sc_parentnodes = array;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this with couple of loops in plain JavaScript. The first loop will populate the base Array with 2 entries. The second one will populate the `sc_parentnodes` node from the base Array with the items from the original () Array. I am sure there are many better/compact ways of doing this, but, this is what I could quickly think of.  Hope this helps.

```js
var data =  [
    {"id": 53,"title": "Scene 1","sc_parentnodes": 0},
    {"id": 54,"title": "Scene 1.1","sc_parentnodes": 53},
    {"id": 55,"title": "Scene 1.2","sc_parentnodes": 53},
    {"id": 56,"title": "Scene 2","sc_parentnodes": 0},
    {"id": 57,"title": "Scene 2.1","sc_parentnodes": 56},
    {"id": 58,"title": "Scene 2.2","sc_parentnodes": 56}
];

var _data = [];
// Loop 1
data.forEach(function(val, ind) {
    if (val.sc_parentnodes === 0) {
        _data.push({
            "id": val.id,
            "title": val.title,
            "sc_parentnodes": []
        });
    }
});

var len = _data.length;
// Loop 2
len && (data.forEach(function(val, ind) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (val.sc_parentnodes === _data[i]["id"]) {
            val.sc_parentnodes = [];
            _data[i]["sc_parentnodes"].push(val);
            break;
        }
    }
}));

console.log ( JSON.stringify(_data, null, 4) );
```